# Why number of matches in fulltext search get less when we put less strings?

Tags: mysql, myisam, full-text-search

```
SELECT * FROM tableauxiliary WHERE MATCH (FullTextSearch)
AGAINST ('resta*' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

show 5 results

```
SELECT * FROM tableauxiliary WHERE MATCH (FullTextSearch)
AGAINST ('restaurant*' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

shows 56k

What am I missing? How can something contains restaurant without containing resta

I am using mysql and MyISAM

Comment: How does your table tableauxiliary look like? are there entries, that contain shorter words than "restaurant" but also start with "resta"?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe more than 50% of your tablerows contain words starting with "resta*".
Words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match.

So you would only have those rows returned, that have a non-common word also starting with "resta*" in your result.

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Try

```
SELECT * FROM tableauxiliary WHERE MATCH (FullTextSearch)
AGAINST ('resta*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Boolean full-text searches have these characteristics: - They do not use the 50% threshold that applies to MyISAM search indexes

I got this here:
[Why does MATCH() give Score 0, if there are less rows in the database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34740/why-does-match-give-score-0-if-there-are-less-rows-in-the-database)